# Why does Wolfram say domain of $y=\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2(x+2)}$ is $x \in \mathcal{R} : x \ge 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-domain

Why does Wolfram say domain of $$y=\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2(x+2)}$$ is $$x \in \mathcal{R} : x \ge 2$$ when I think is actually all real numbers because it's third root? Even google's quick answer is saying that, but they are probably just using Wolfram and showing the result as their own.

Comment: I think  your answer is right.

Comment: I have no idea where $2$ would even come from. If it were $x\geq -2$, I'd see why WA had said what it said. I wouldn't agree, but I would understand.

Comment: WA said [$-2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain+of+((x-1)%5E2*(x%2B2))%5E(1%2F3)) to me

Comment: This is the problem with power $1/3$. Have a look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain+of+cuberoot%28%28x-1%29%5E2+%28x%2B2%29%29

Comment: Really weird stuff.

Comment: This is why they introduced *CubeRoot* function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution to this can be found when you input the equation in wolfram alpha:
[image]

It appears that wolfram alpha considers negative values outside of the domain of the principal root. If you click on "Use the real-valued root" you will get the expected answer.

[image: Domain: R]

Answer (score 2):

WA always thinks that $x^{\frac{1}{3}}=\sqrt[3]{x},$ but it's wrong.

By definition, the domain of $x^r$, where $r\in\mathbb Q$, is $(0,+\infty)$.

The domain of $\sqrt[n]{x}$, where $n\in\mathbb N$, $n$ is even and $n\geq2$, is $[0,+\infty)$;

The domain of $\sqrt[n]{x}$, where $n\in\mathbb N$, $n$ is odd and $n\geq3$, is $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Thr answer of Wolfram is not correct: in fact $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is defined $\forall x \in R$ (also negative or $0$). So in your case $\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2(x+2)}$ is defined $\forall x \in R$

Comment: Danken very much.

Comment: And do you know why it said that?

Comment: I completely don't know. Maybe it can be a bug.